# getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'" when trying to run my code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I made a Selenium bot on my local Mac, where it works flawlessly. When trying to run it on a virtual Windows 10 machine via google cloud, I'm getting these errors:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ahamed_a_1235\instabot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import undetected_chromedriver as uc
  File "C:\Users\ahamed_a_1235\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-
packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from .patcher import IS_POSIX
  File "C:\Users\ahamed_a_1235\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-
packages\undetected_chromedriver\patcher.py", line 4, in <module>
    from distutils.version import LooseVersion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
PS C:\Users\ahamed_a_1235>"
```

Please help. Here are screenshots with related details:

[image]

[image]

I tried installing the libraries again, but still have the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Just upgrade, it helped to solve this issue

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

- Have you checked if Python development libraries are installed?

```py
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

- After this is done, you can install undetected-chromium like so:

```py
pip install undetected-chromedriver
```

- I can also see that you are using Python 3.12. The entire distutils package is deprecated in this Python version. [Refer this](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/distutils.html)

Comment: yes python dev libraries is already installed

Comment: im not sure what to do about diskutils being deprecated, im very new to python

Comment: install an older version of  python and check if it works

Answer (score 0):

- Install an older python version

or

- use some other package to replace undetected-chromedriver

distutils package is removed from python 3.12 and undetected-chromedriver uses this package to get LooseVersion

undetected-chromedriver package needs to get updated soon